# Split a String into 2 Variables

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, split

What I'm trying to do here is Capture 2 Variables from a Textbox

Here is an example of whats going to be in here.

`User:Pass`

I want to declare everything before the `:` as user and everything after the `:` as pass.

I've Googled, and found a few things, but I couldn't seem to get it working fully.

Comment: But Now, If I wanted to do multiple lines like this, what would i DO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Dim words As String() = textbox1.text.Split(":")
Dim user as String =  words(0)
Dim pass as String =  words(1)
```

Comment: @user1378687 Just miss the language tag. I have edited my answer for vb.net.

Comment: I believe this works as well :D, Just Selected this as the answer, this seems to Work Easier than the one above.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim str = "User:Pass"

Dim split = str.Split(":")

Dim user as String
Dim password as String

If (split.Count = 2) then
    user=split(0).ToString()
    password = split(1).ToString()
End If
```

Split on the **`:`**, if there are 2 entries in the resulting array, populate the user variable with the first item, and the password variable with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the split function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim user As String
Dim pass As String
Dim iPosEQ As Integer
iPosEQ = textbox1.text.IndexOf(":", System.StringComparison.Ordinal)
kv(0) = textbox1.text.Substring(0, iPosEQ - 1)
kv(1) = textbox1.text.Substring(iPosEQ + 1)
```

This works even with passwords (or users) with ":"

Comment: This is very weird... undeclared but used kv, declared but unused user/pass... and what has the textbox1 to do with the question?!? This does NOT work if there are : in user (this cuts on first found!). Life is not that much complicated...